# Reducing size of an image in PySide

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

My requirement is to reduce the size of an image and display in a square box(50 x 50). If the size of the image is less than the size of the square box , the image should be displayed as it is. As an initial attempt I tried with the below code, with the intention to reduce the size of all images with:

```
picSize = QtCore.QSize(lbl.width() / 2 , lbl.height() / 2)
```

But the below code is not reducing the size of image even after using:

```
picSize = QtCore.QSize(lbl.width() / 4 , lbl.height() / 4)
```

Please help me.

```
import os
import sys

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class SecondExample(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondExample, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.imgFolder = os.getcwd()


        self.widgetLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollarea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.widgetLayout.addWidget(self.scrollarea)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)    
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        for img in os.listdir(self.imgFolder):
            imgPath = os.path.join(self.imgFolder, img)
            actualImage = QtGui.QImage(imgPath)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(imgPath)

            lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

            lbl.setScaledContents(True)

            picSize = QtCore.QSize(lbl.width() / 2 , lbl.height() / 2)
            lbl.resize(picSize)

            self.layout.addWidget(lbl)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 900, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Viewer')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SecondExample()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will achieve your requirement:

```
            imgPath = os.path.join(self.imgFolder, img)
            actualImage = QtGui.QImage(imgPath)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(imgPath)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(500, 500, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio) 
            lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

            lbl.setScaledContents(True)
```

Comment: What does "actualImage = QtGui.QImage(imgPath)" do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `scaledToWidth` or scaledToHeight`method on the`QImage` class.

```
img= QtGui.QImage(imgPath)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img.scaledToWidth(50))
lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to scale the `QPixmap` using [`QPixmap::scaled`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPixmap.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QPixmap.scaled).

`pixmap.scaled(picSize)`

And you might want to check [AspectRatio](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Qt.html?highlight=spectratio#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode).